# Highlight certain words in input form without using tags?

Tags: javascript

I need to highlight certain words in Twitter input form as user types their tweet but apparently Twitter has a script that protects the form and removes any HTML tags that I put in there. Is there any way to do this without using tags?

Comment: What code are you using? What kind of input is this, and why does Twitter have control over it? Are you trying to highlight words on an actual Twitter page? Did you want the highlights submitted with the tweet? (That last one is not possible, if Twitter has any sense of decent sanitization of input.)

Comment: To somehow emphasize input text you may convert typed characters to a funny unicode range. See https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/ for an example. No tags, just crazy unicode. Highlight is not an option I'm afraid.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk No, I don't need to submit the highlights with the tweet, it's only for the user to see (e.g. spellchecker). I am using a simple script to find certain words in the input form as user types and then it changes the input's value by wrapping this word in <span>. It does work for a moment, but the next second Twitter's script sanitizes the form and removes any HTML tags inside. Is there any workaround for a situation like this?

Comment: @AntonRusak but won't it push the unicode characters as the actual tweet then? I only need highlights for the user to see as their type in their tweet.

Comment: Can you please post the code you're currently using? Or at least the code you're using from Twitter that's causing your issues? I would think you'd be able to use your own inputs for a value and pass it to Twitter's API.

Comment: @Albert you could replace them with regular versions before posting to twitter. Guess you develop a browser extension or userscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use `getBoundingClientRect()` and draw an overlay over the box while the user is writting.

`getBoundingClientRect()` is expensive, but running at user *typing speed* is no problem actually.

It will return the absolute position of the element from the top/left margin of the window, so you can create an absolute (or fixed I guess) element over the box and set the received position to your elements.

I guess that the fastest way is to process the text and create HTML tags like you do now, and then get the `getBoundingClientRect()` and create the overlay of each tag. Twitter then will reset the input to whatever it wants, but you already got the `getBoundingClientRect()` as long as you do that in the same event loop when you create your tags (before Twitter modify nothing).

**IMPORTANT:** Don't forget to add `pointer-events` CSS to `none` so no mouse clicks are catch by your overlay.

[pointer-events documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

[getBoundingClientRect documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)